# Using dom-if in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

`dom-if` is not working in the given code. The code is processing and in debugging it also returns true. But the template is not displaying!

Why the template is not displaying?

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[persistedProducts]]" as="product">
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{isProductLiked(product)}}">
    <paper-button on-click="dislikeThisProduct" 
      title="Click to UnLike" class="title-rose">
      <iron-icon icon="icons:thumb-up" class="title-rose" style="width:28px; height:17px;"></iron-icon>
      Liked
    </paper-button>
  </template>
</template>

isProductLiked: function(product) {
  let uid = this.user.uid;

  //Add visitor/user details here..
  this.$.queryProductLikes.disabled = false;
  this.$.queryProductLikes.ref.child(product.$key).child(uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.val() != null) {
      //Display Like - if Liked.
      if(snapshot.val().isLiked) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    } else {
      //Not Liked
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `isProductLiked` function:

```
this.$.queryProductLikes.ref.child(product.$key).child(uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.val() != null) {
    if (snapshot.val().isLiked) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

You use an anonymous function here (`... function(snapshot) { ...`), so when you return `true` or `false` you aren't returning in the `isProductLiked` function, but in this anonymous function.

**Edit**

I am not familiar with Firebase so these may or may not work:

**Possible solution #1**

1. Query the product likes outside of the `isProductLiked` function.
2. Set a property based on the result. (Lets call it `productLikes` for this example)
3. Use this result in the `dom-if` like this: `<template is="dom-if" if="{{isProductLiked(product, productLikes)}}">`
4. Modify the `isProductLiked` function to include the `productLikes` parameter and to handle the new logic.

The idea here is, to remove any async function call from the `isProductLiked` function.

**Possible solution #2**

Redesign the data storage and query, so the `persistedProducts` contains the likes too. So you could write the `dom-if` like this: `<template is="dom-if" if="{{product.isLiked}}">`.

Comment: Thanks! Hunex. Function (isProductLiked) returns 'undefined'. What should be the correct way..?

Comment: Can you provide more info? I see you are using some sort of storage here, is it Firebase?

Comment: Yes, it's Firebase and I'm adding storage of ProductKey liked by user. And at display page of product I want to check if the displayed product is Liked by user or not and based on that I'll display 'Like' or 'UnLike' button.

Comment: As @Hunex said, you should be storing the likes in a local property and passing that to the `isProductLiked` computed binding.

Comment: Thanks! Hunex and DocDude I'm using similar to solution #2.